# I want to buy a product but they only accept credit cards so can I apply for one and buy the product?

Tags: halal-haram, banking

Iam a student from india.I want to use adobe products and using pirated version is is haram so i want to buy genuine products.Adobe provide their products for 1 year subscription monthly(annual plan-paid monthly)
The only payment they accept is through credit card as they do not accept debitcard.

so if i apply for a credit card and purchase the product with it also repaying the money within the due date(mostly within 2 days i will repay the money) and not causing or leading to a interest.
does it will be haraam
also i know that by getting a credit card iam agreeing to their agreement thatif i didnt repayed within due date i have to pay interest
and also these credit card banks charge the retailer some money when i purchase from them
there is no otherway for me and the only way to purchase these things is through credit card 
CAN I?

Comment: Using pirated software may be less haram than engaging in riba.

Comment: You can try getting a debit card.

Answer (score 2):

I am from India and in same situation like yours. I need to make payments for hosting and other services through credit card. Recently I got a credit card from my bank which has auto debit feature, which means on due date whatever balance is due from me, it is debited from my savings account. This way I never have to pay any interest, if I ensure there is sufficient balance in my account on the due date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. But in order for this not to cross the haram line you should have all the money at hand. If you don't have complete amount of money to be paid and you will enter the credit card agreement then this would be haram because you would be borrowing money on the terms of usury. But if you have all the money at hand then you would be using the credit services for money transfering and not for usury. It can be called credit on pappers but that does not make it credit, facts are what matter. As prophet Mohammad said, "Actions are according to intentions, and everyone will get what was intended". And in your actions you will not be using the terms of agreement related to usury. Also the money the bank has to charge you are simply payment for the transfer services.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepaid Credit Card , Or Debit Card ( if accepted by adobe )
if Your local bank do not offer debit cards or prepaid credit cards you can create account on online money transfer service that offer those cards like Wise , Payoneer , etc ... , there also services that offer virtual cards , But Please Check if They Are accepted By adobe Before use any service
Have A nice day